# how can get dailect object from hibernate template for maniplate db

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, database-design

```
String driverName = this.getSession().connection().getMetaData().getDriverName();
if (driverName.contains(Const.DATABASE_SQLSERVER)) {
    ps = this.getSession().connection()
            .prepareStatement("select next value for " + seqName + " as nextval");
} else if (driverName.contains(Const.DATABASE_ORACLE)) {
    ps = this.getSession().connection()
             .prepareStatement("select " + seqName + ".nextval from dual");
} else if (driverName.contains(Const.DATABASE_MYSQL)) {
   //...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: fixed formatting (mode from quote to code block), closed scope. else clause missing so put comment in place for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information as follows:

```
    SessionFactoryImpl factoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactoryObject; 
    Properties properties = factoryImpl.getProperties();
    String dialect = properties.get("dialect").toString();
```